# PostgreSQL WHERE and null

Tags: python, postgresql, null, where-clause

I have a table which looks like this:
[image]

When I try to look up only the row with case_id = 5 based on pr, sr, sn, I use the following code:

```
SELECT case_id, dupl_cnt
FROM cases
WHERE pr = NULLIF('', '')::INT AND
      sr = NULLIF('CH_REP13702.10000', '')::VARCHAR AND
      sn = NULLIF('22155203912', '')::VARCHAR
```

However, the code above does not yield any result (empty query result). I have narrowed it down to being some sort of an issue with the "pr" value being null - when "pr" removed line is removed from the above query, it starts to work as expected. Can someone explain to me why is that happening? I am anticipating pr or sr columns at times to feature NULL values, but still have to be able to look up case_id numbers with them.
(NULLIF function is in there because it is a part of Python integration with psycopg2 module, and I have to anticipate that sometimes data entry will feature empty string for these values).

Comment: Because NULL is not the same as an empty string?

Comment: I don`t follow. Running query SELECT NULLIF('', '') returns a cell with [null] value for me. Doesn`t that satisfy pr = [null] condition?

Comment: What IDE/tool is that table screenshot from?

Comment: Parfait: pgAdmin4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NULLIF('', '')` returns `[null]`

that deos'nt that satisfy the pr = [null] condition because

*anything* `= NULL`  returns `NULL`

You need to use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` instead of `=`